# How to have user directory for GNOME wallpapers

Tags: arch-linux, gnome, wallpaper

I have my wallpapers stored on Dropbox organized by dimensions and I would like to have them available to GNOME. However, I have found this is absurdely hard to do, as even complex searches on various engines render useless results.

I can not have them stored on the global path (`/usr/share/backgrounds`) as this computer has a lot of users and they shouldn't be able to choose my wallpapers. Also, I would like to keep them stored on different directories for every dimension. I don't mind updating 5 or 6 lines if I add another directory.

Where is the default path for users, if there is any, or how can I enable this and have my own wallpapers?

Comment: Which version of Gnome are you using?

Comment: @Wilf 3.12.1, the latest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd look to use an application to do this. Here are 2 ways that I've used on Fedora and CentOS in the past, but I would assume that both these approaches would work for Arch as well.

#### Wallpapoz

Is an applet that runs in your GNOME taskbar.

- You can download the RPM from [here](http://pkgs.org/download/wallpapoz) for various Fedora/CentOS versions.
- The main site for it is [here](http://vajrasky.wordpress.com/wallpapoz/).
- The main github tree is [here](https://github.com/vajrasky/wallpapoz).

[image: ss of wallpapoz]

#### Shell script

Here's a bash script that will cycle through a list of images.

```
#!/bin/bash
#Default values
pictdir="$HOME/Pictures"
time=1h

#Wallpaper names
fnme=('wp1.jpg' 'wp2.jpg' 'wp3.jpg')

fin=${#fnme[@]}
let bck=$fin-1

#Exit if the script is already running, just in case
#Got this part of script somewhere in this forum
if pidof -x $(basename $0) > /dev/null; then
  for p in $(pidof -x $(basename $0)); do
    if [ $p -ne $$ ]; then
      echo "Script $0 is already running: exiting"
      exit
    fi
  done
fi

#This is where the desktop wallpaper changes
for (( i=0;i<$fin;i++ )); do
    sleep $time #wait for $time second(s)
    gconftool-2 --type string --set /desktop/gnome/background/picture_filename $pictdir/${fnme[${i}]}
    if [ $i -eq $bck ]; then
         let i=-1
    fi
done
```

It makes use of `gconftool-2`. I haven't tried this on **CentOS 6.x** yet so it might require some tweaking, but I have used it on **Fedora** and **CentOS 5.x**. The script is courtesy of this [linuxquestions thread](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/a-script-to-change-wallpaper-776587/).

#### Wallch

Available [here](http://wall-changer.sourceforge.net/). Haven't tried it but it's purported to work on `GNOME 2 & 3`. There's a nice review of Wallch [here](http://ashu-geek.blogspot.com/2012/03/wallch-30-wallpaper-changer-for-gnome.html).

[image: ss wallch]

#### Dropbox

With either of these approaches you can simply point them into your DropBox synced folder where the images are being kept. I use something similar using SparkleShare to sync my wallpaper images across my various systems.

Comment: It seems ridiculously dumb needing to use another application for something GNOME already does for me, it just is so badly documented.

Comment: @ranisalt - agreed but sometimes it's about getting a task done and working, not that the solution is glamorous 8-).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, I agree that this is suprisingly hard to do. What I have found out it that the right way to do this is to add an XML file to `~/.local/share/gnome-background-properties/`. This XML should contain references to all your wallpapers.
You can probably find an example file in `/usr/share/gnome-background-properties`.

I know this doesn't really answer your question, but it might get you started. I got most of this from [here](http://www.reddit.com/r/gnome/comments/1bs9os/is_there_a_way_to_add_a_new_directory_to_the/)

Comment: Strangely enough, adding the xml file to `~/.local/share/gnome-background-properties/` did nothing.

Comment: It worked for me on (Gnome 40). I copied /usr/share/gnome-background-properties/gnome-backgrounds.xml to ~/.local/share/gnome-background-properties/gnome-backgrounds.xml and changed name tags to not collide with existing wallpapers and they appeared in the Background settings.